# fc-cache and fc-list

Tags: fonts, fontconfig

I'm using XeLaTeX which is based on `fontconfig`. The problem is about `fc-cache` and `fc-list`. The problem is the following:

1. I noticed that in the folder `/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm` I have a lot of `.otf` fonts.
2. I know that its name is `Latin Modern Roman`, but doing `fc-list | grep Latin` I cannot find anything;
3. So I update cache doing `fc-cache -fv /usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm`, here it's the result

   ```
   /usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm: caching, new cache contents: 72 fonts, 0 dirs
   /var/cache/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
   /root/.cache/fontconfig: not cleaning non-existent cache directory
   /root/.fontconfig: not cleaning non-existent cache directory fc-cache: succeeded
   ```
4. however doing again `fc-list | grep Latin` I don't get anything. What is the problem? How can I have that font in my cache?

Comment: What user are you running this as?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try as:
`sudo chmod 644 *`
on your fonts directory
`/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm`.